# Unable to create db link between oracle12c and mysql8

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

```
OS= windows 10,
Oracle= 12c,
Mysql= 8
```

I use the following step on this webpage https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mysql-odbc-oracle-hs.rst
to create db link but.

When I try to query mysql table from oracle (sql plus) the following error happened

```
SQL> SELECT * from "Orders"@mymysqldb WHERE ShipCountry = 'USA';
SELECT * from "Orders"@mymysqldb WHERE ShipCountry = 'USA';
                   *

ERROR at line 1: ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to
an agent Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MYSQL
```

All configuration is based on the above link. But I could not understand what is happened.

Comment: have you checked if there is an error message?

Comment: There is nothing about a db link that should prevent an oracle instance from starting -- even if the link is badly configured.  Nothing about the link is accessed until it is actually called in a SQL statement.  If your oracle instance is not starting you need to be looking in the alert log for relevant error messages.